# Code First DB deadlock

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, repository

So, I am using Code First approach to building an application and ran into a little problem while saving an entity in the db.

Here is my entity:

```
public class Customer
{
  public Customer()
  {
    Addresses = new List<Address>();
    PhoneNumbers = new List<Phone>();
  }

  public Guid CustomerID { get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Phone> PhoneNumbers { get; set;}
  public virtual Address MailingAddress {get; set;}
  public virtual Phone DefaultPhone {get; set;}
}
```

Now, this creates an entry in the Address and Phone table called Customer_CustomerID, and an entry in the Customer table of DefaultPhone_PhoneID and MailingAddress_AddressID, both Guids.

Whenever I save my entity, I receive the following message:

```
"Inner Exception: Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.”
```

I have a feeling it has to do with the way these entities are being hooked up, do you notice anything wrong or something I'm missing?

This is how the entity is saved:

```
public ActionResult CreateCustomer(Address address, Phone phone)
{
  Customer cust = new Customer();

  repository.Phone_Save(phone);
  cust.PhoneNumbers.add(phone);
  cust.DefaulPhone = phone;

  repository.Address_Save(address);
  cust.Addresses.add(address);
  cust.MailingAddress = address;

  repository.Customer_Save(cust);
 }

 public void Customer_Save(Customer customer);
 {
  Customer entity = context.Customers.Find(customer.CustomerID);

        if (entity == null)
        {

            context.Customers.Add(customer);
            entity = customer;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(customer);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
        context.Entry(entity).Reload();}
```

Comment: Are you also storing a `MailingAddress` and/or `DefaultPhone` in this process?

Comment: I apologize for answering this late, I have updated my code.

Comment: There you go. If all entities are new, EF must wait for generated PK values to store these into the various FKs values. So the new phone must be stored before the new customer. However, the customer must be stored before the phone because the phone needs an FK to customer (because of `cust.PhoneNumbers`). Circular associations. Unfortunately, it is not apparent from your code how to fix this. In particular the context's scope is not clear, and I suspect that there are more `SaveChanges` calls.

Comment: Actually that was the reason for the action not saving. Right on the money here!!! If you submit your comment as an answer I'll label it as such :) Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all entities are new, EF must wait for generated PK values to store these into the various FKs values. This causes you a **chicken-and-egg problem**.

The new phone must be stored before the new customer. However, the customer must be stored before the phone because the phone needs an FK to customer (because of cust.PhoneNumbers). Circular associations. Unfortunately, it is not apparent from your code how to fix this. In particular the context's scope is not clear, and I suspect that there are more `SaveChanges` calls.

A general way to deal with this situation is wrapping several `SaveChanges` calls in a [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx). The first call returns the generated PK values which can be used as FK values for a subsequent `SaveChanges` call.